# Pandas / numpy get top 10 from matrix

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am computing a similarity matrix where the result is very large and I would like to reduce the size.

Here is an current code I have:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import linear_kernel
from sql_con import get_con

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

df = df[['id','value1', 'value2']]

df = df.set_index('id')

sim= squareform(pdist(df, metric='cosine'))

sim_df= pd.DataFrame(sim,columns = df.index,index = df.index)

table= sim_df.unstack()

table.index.rename(['id_1', 'id_2'], inplace=True)
table= table.to_frame('distance')
table.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

The result data table would look something like the following

```
id_1 id_2 distance

 a    b      0.1
 a    c      0.2
```

In order to reduce the size, for each element/id in the matrix I would only like to take the top n (for example 10) closest/most similar elements, effectively this would actually mean getting the smallest 10.

I have tried to reduce the size of the data once it is in the data frame "table" variable, but because of how pandas works, any steps taken to reduce the data size will increase/spike the memory usage. For this reason, I would like to see what the option are toe reduce the size of the data while it is still a numpy array (the variable "sim").

What is an efficient (in terms of both memory and time) way to reduce the size of this matrix by only taking the top n closest ids for each id.

Comment: seems you're looking for `np.argpartition`

Comment: How do you plan to use the 'compact' matrix? As I understand, you currently have a mapping `(Element,OtherElement)->Similarity` encoded in a symmetric matrix and you want a mapping `(Element, Rank)->(OtherElement,Similarity)` that is valid for `Rank` between 1 and 10. Is that correctly understood?

Comment: ideally I would want to go from a symmetric matrix to an id pairwise distance table like the one added above

Comment: Hello @MustardTiger, I have updated my answer to give you an id pairwise distance table like in your updated question.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem correctly, you have a very huge matrix, and you would like to decrease its dimensionality somehow.

One approach I can think of that should be fairly efficient is to do the following.

This approach assumes you have an m*m similarity matrix, `sim`, whose indexes correspond with `df.index`. i.e sim[i] corresponds with the row of similarity values for the first index label.

While I am unsure of how to find `sim`, I think this should do, per my understanding on this [page](https://drawingfromdata.com/pandas/clustering/making-a-pairwise-distance-matrix-in-pandas.html) and based on your question:

```
sim = squareform(pdist(df, metric='cosine'))
```

The rest is as follows:

```py
n = 10

# an array that stores each label in its corresponding index position in sim matrix
index_labels = df.index.to_numpy()

# get the top n indexes with highest similarity for each row in the matrix (i.e the 'reduced' matrix)
highest_similarity_idxs = np.argsort(sim, axis=1)[:, :n]

# get the labels of the highest similarity items
highest_similarity_labels = index_labels[highest_similarity_idxs]

# highest similar labels for label at pos 0
label = index_labels[0] # any label you are interested in
row_idx = index_labels.tolist().index(label)
most_similar_labels = highest_similarity_labels[row_index]

# get the actual similarity values for each row
highest_similarity_values = np.take_along_axis(sim, highest_similarity_idxs, axis=1)
```

#### Converting to an id pairwise dataframe

To get things as a dataframe in the style that you want, you would add on the following:

```py
data = {
  'id_1': np.repeat(index_labels, n),
  'id_2': highest_similarity_labels.flatten(),
  'distance': highest_similarity_values.flatten()
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

NB: for the resulting table to match up correctly, the labels in `index_labels` must correspond with the row indexes in `sim` matrix.

For example given the following `index_labels` and `sim` matrix, we have:

```py
index_labels = np.array(['a', 'b'])
sim = np.array([[0, 0.2], 
                [0.3, 0]])

# sim[0, 1] is the distance from the label 'a' to 'b' which is 0.2
# sim[0, 0] is the distance from the label 'a' to 'a' which is 0, etc.
```

I hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Tested it out, works great. no memory issues and runs quite fast as opposed to the pandas implementation I was trying before

Comment: Nice, and happy to hear that. NumPy is phenomenal at making things faster.